# Why data files are different on master slave nodes?

Tags: postgresql, master-slave-replication

I recently set up a Postgres15 master-slave (Primary-secondary) cluster on 2 nodes. At the time of starting, I ensured that data files are exactly the same on both the nodes. The size of the DB is 1.5TB.
The directory structure on both nodes looks as follows:

```
  - /PROD/datadg/
   |
   |-> /PROD/datadg/tablespace
   |   |-> /PROD/datadg/tablespace/tablespace1
   |   |-> /PROD/datadg/tablespace/tablespace2
   |
   |-> /PROD/datadg/data
   |   |-> /PROD/datadg/data/pg_tblspc
   |   |   | -> /PROD/datadg/data/pg_tblspc/16432 -> /PROD/datadg/tablespace/tablespace1
   |   |   | -> /PROD/datadg/data/pg_tblspc/16433 -> /PROD/datadg/tablespace/tablespace2
```

Almost a week later now, I see almost 2GB size difference in the tablespace folders on the 2 nodes. I also see some file count difference on both the nodes.

`autovacuum` is on on both the nodes and there isn't any `idle in transaction` queries on the slave node. Also there hasn't been any disruption on the streaming replication. I did not get any error like `WAL segment already removed` or so on the slave node. `pg_stat_replication` on the master node also doesn't show anything out of the odd and the `sent_lsn`, `write_lsn` and `flush_lsn` are regularly updated. I can not see difference in counts of most tables either, haven't verified for all of them.
So my **first question** is:

- Why is there a difference in the files in the tablespace folder? I can understand the difference in the modification timestamps, but some files are just missing on the slave node.

Now if I were to run `vacuumdb` on the master node, there are chances that the slave node will break and give an error like this

```
PANIC,XX000,"WAL contains references to invalid pages",,,,,"WAL redo at 875E/21A70BD0 for
 Heap2/VISIBLE: cutoff xid 60350476 flags 0x01; blkref #0: rel 16405/16419/533716933, fork 2, blk 26; blkref #1: rel 16405/16419/533716933, blk 853758",,,,"","startup
```

In the case when slave node breaks, these are the steps I usually do to bring the slave node back:

1. Start `pg_backup_start('backup')` on the master node
2. rsync the files from master to slave by running the following on the slave node:

```
rsync -av --delete master_node:/PROD/datadg/data/ /PROD/datadg/data --exclude 'pg_log' --exclude 'pg_replslot'
```

3. Stop `pg_backup_stop()` on  master node
4. Start the slave node again and it usually works, even though the tablespace files might not still be the same.

**Second question**:

- What is the best way to bring the slave node back? Is the `rsync` between tablespaces required? And if yes, what is the best method to do it for very large databases, something maybe as big as 30TB or more. I don't want to `rsync` all the files even if only the timestamp on them is different. So is a command like this safe to do? Or should an option like `--checksum` be used?

```
rsync -av --delete master_node:/PROD/datadg/tablespace/ /PROD/datadg/tablespace --size-only
```

**Third question:**

- Is it advised to run `vacuumdb` before or after bringing the slave node back again?

**Edit 1:**

How I created the master-slave nodes (with no data except the one from initdb on master node)?

1. Config file for master node

```
wal_level = logical
synchronous_commit = remote_write
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'rsync -a %p /PROD/wal_archive/%f'
#archive_command = ':'
max_wal_senders=10
hot_standby = on
restart_after_crash = off
wal_sender_timeout = 5000
wal_receiver_status_interval = 2
max_standby_streaming_delay = -1
max_standby_archive_delay = -1
hot_standby_feedback = on
random_page_cost = 1.5
wal_keep_size = 0
```

2. On master node, create replica user

```
CREATE ROLE replica WITH Replication Login Superuser;
```

3. Whitelist replica user on master node and reload
4. Stop the already running PG instance on the slave node
5. Issue `pg_backup_start('backup')` on master node
6. rsync to standby node using

```
rsync -av --delete master_node:/PROD/datadg/data/ /PROD/datadg/data --exclude 'pg_log' --exclude 'pg_replslot'
```

6. Issue `pg_backup_stop()` on master node
7. `touch standby.signal` on slave node
8. Change the `postgresql.conf` on slave node and add

```
primary_conninfo = 'host=master_node's ip port=5432 user=replica application_name=host_name keepalives_idle=60 keepalives_interval=5 keepalives_count=5'
restore_command = 'rsync -a /PROD/wal_archive/%f %p'
recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'
```

9. Start the slave node
10. Check the replication status on master node.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions about the 'backup label file' and the 'tablespace map file' given under [pg_backup_stop](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html)?  You don't describe doing so, and I'm guessing that that is the problem.

Comment: I don't know why, but you are experiencing data corruption. Delete the standby and start from scratch. If you want an answer, please edit the question and describe how exactly you created the standby server.

Comment: @jjanes I looked at the pg_backup_stop, but didn't understand the meaning of "must be written to files in the backup area". I issued `pg_backup_start('backup') and `pg_backup_stop()` commands, but they didn't create any backup label file. I only saw the output on the psql client.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I edited to add the details about how I created the standby server. I understand from jjanes comment that I might be missing the backup label file and tablespace map, but I don't know where they are and what should be the rsync command for that. I used to do these steps as per my understanding of [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/backup-online.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your procedure is wrong, and the backup is missing the `backup_label` file that contains the checkpoint that you need to recover the standby from. Consequently, you recovered from the wrong checkpoint (the one in the control file). Unfortunately you did not encounter an error, so you ended up with a corrupted server.

The correct way to call `pg_backup_stop()` is

```
SELECT labelfile FROM pg_backup_stop();
```

You have to capture the output and create a file `backup_label` in the data directory of the standby with these contents. Note that `pg_backup_start()` and `pg_backup_stop()` must be called in the same database session.

For further reading, look at [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-LOWLEVEL-BASE-BACKUP) and [this article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/exclusive-backup-deprecated-what-now/).

Comment: Thanks! Btw I guess you mean `pg_backup_start()` and `pg_backup_stop()` in the same session? So if I create the labelfile and put in the data directory for my slave node, and start my PG instance, then the data would not be corrupted? And I should remove that labelfile afterwards? Any advice on using `rsync --size-only` option or any other option to make it faster and not sync the whole 1TB?

Comment: Correct. But you never manually remove a file in the data directory. PostgreSQL will remove (actually rename) the file automatically when it is appropriate.

Comment: @AbhishekB   You can't use --size-only.  You also can't reliably use timestamps, either, you need the checksum feature.